# Comment traduire « Ask away! » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, interjections

En anglais, cette phrase est une expression d'encouragement à quelqu'un, une manière de l'inviter à poser n'importe quelle question de son choix.

Comment la traduire en français ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Je suis tout ouïe.

ou bien

> Je t'écoute, tu as toute mon attention.

Answer (score 10):

I would more say something like "vas-y", "dis-moi" if this is about encouraging people to complete his action.

Comment: Plutôt « Allez, vas-y dis-moi tout ! »

Answer (score 3):

In French, "Ask away" could be translated as "Dites-moi", "Dis-moi tout"

Answer (score 2):

> Posez-là !

... si j'en crois [*Linguee*](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=ask%20away).

---

*Complément suite au commentaire de Laure*

Dans une discussion, lorsque quelqu'un hésite à poser une question qui peut paraître gênante, hors sujet, ou que la bonne formule n'est pas encore arrivée à maturité on peut l'encourager en le pressant un peu :

> Mais pose donc ta question !
>
> On t'écoute [avec attention (*si l'on est respectueux du locuteur*)]
>
> Accouche ! *ou* Vas-y, accouche !   (*familier, plus autoritaire*)

Comment: Pas vraiment, tu n'as pas chois le bon contexte parmi les choix proposées par linguee. Posez-là ne contient pas la notion d'encouragement que donne le *away* de l'expression anglaise,  à la rigueur, « posez-la donc ».  Attention à Linguee, pas toujours fiable, et il faut toujours étudier le contexte dans les deux langues.

Comment: @Laure La traduction de Linguee m'avais semblé tellement *évidente* que je n'ai pas cherché à l'approfondir. À la réflexion il y a plusieurs moyens, plusieurs niveaux d'encouragements que j'ai essayé de préciser dans le complément de ma réponse ; merci de votre remarque.

Comment: Maybe adding "sans gêne" to your original "posez-la"/"posez-les" would be another acceptable way to augment the notion of encouragement, if necessary: [posez-les sans gêne!](http://so-nantes.com/prefecture-nantes-10-conseils-reussir-rendez-vous/) (item 3 under "BIEN SE PRESENTER")

Answer (score 2):

Un complément même si je préfère les réponses basées sur l'impératif du verbe *poser* (la question) ou sur une construction ou une autre avec le verbe *aller* pour signaler le départ. Le « *ask away* » c'est en fait surtout un « [fire away](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/fire-away) » (*I know you have questions, so fire away*. - [*TFD*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fire+away)) appliqué à l'univers des questions et commande donc en effet, à l'impératif, le début de l'expression:

> [Exprimez](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exprimer)-vous! ([s'exprimer](http://www.conjugaison.com/conjuguer.php?verbe=s%27exprimer))

Dans un contexte où il y a un exposé puis des questions, c'est assez courant à mon avis. Peut-être même utilisé alors qu'il n'y a pas assez de questions (donc un encouragement avec une légère remontrance). L'essence du verbe est « faire sortir ».<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. Dans une moindre mesure, certains verbes reliés au mouvement rapide (du tir) sont parfois aussi utiles comme [*lancer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lancer) (dans le sens de *dire avec force*, peut-être même par analogie *se lancer*, mais attention au ton de *lancer un [trait](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trait)*). Une particularité régionale (Québec), à l'oral uniquement, familier, possiblement un anglicisme, l'emploi de [*shoot*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/shoot) (n.) ou une forme ressemblant à *shooter* (v.) (l'allégorie [sportive](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/shooter)), mais uniquement utilisé avec un interlocuteur spécifique au singulier de l'impératif ([*shoote*](http://www.conjugaison.com/conjuguer.php?verbe=shooter)) pour susciter l'expression ou indiquer qu'on est prêt à recevoir la question.</sub>.

Answer (score 2):

A part la réponse de Foucha, la majorité des réponses sont relativement agressives et ne véhiculent pas la connotation d'encouragement.

Une version encourageante et moins familière serait simplement : « Je vous en prie... », peut-être dans le contexte d'un cours.

Pour une conversation courante « je t'en prie » serait trop sophistiqué. « Vas-y » ou « dis-moi » seraient plus appropriés.

Answer (score 1):

« J'écoute ! » en regardant son interlocuteur dans les yeux, traduit la même idée. Une fois de plus, toutes ces expressions dépendent d'un contexte particulier et peuvent être traduites de plusieurs manières.

Answer (score 1):

'Vas y; poses ta/tes question(s)'. Ou bien: 'Demandes moi; je t' écoute.' Ou bien: 'Demandes moi; je suis tout(e) ouie.'

Answer (score 0):

Pour rendre l'effet de mouvement et le ton de langage, je proposerais

> Balancez vos questions ! / Balance tes questions !

Ce n'est pas agressif, c'est une manière de faire comprendre qu'on est prêt à répondre à tout.

Cette formule se combine d'ailleurs à merveille avec le *vas-y* incitatif déjà cité à juste titre par Foucha.

> **Vas-y, balance tes questions !**